# Detect scroll intent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I once came across a script or article about the following issue:

Imagine a page which is scrollable with multiple elements inside that are also scrollable. When scrolling down the page, the cursor will come across elements that are scrollable, and they will take focus. Resulting in having to either remove your cursor from that element, or scrolling down that element before you're able to scroll the entire page again.

The demo I saw fixed that issue by only focussing on the scrollable elements after cursor movement or some sort of interruption of the scrolling. So when you would scroll down the page you could keep scrolling (floating over the scrollable elements) without interruptions.

Does anyone know what script I'm talking about?

Comment: I advice you to NOT CHANGE THIS BY USER EXPECTED BEHAVOIR!

Comment: @Bondye The topics you posted (and removed) were totally different questions

Answer (score 0):

If I understood ok otherwise let me know: if you want to detect scroll event then you have to use [scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) from jquery page.

try this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  div { color:blue; }
  p { color:green; }
  span { color:red; display:none; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>Try scrolling the iframe.</div>
  <p>Paragraph - <span>Scroll happened!</span></p>
<script>
    $("p").clone().appendTo(document.body);
    $("p").clone().appendTo(document.body);
    $("p").clone().appendTo(document.body);
    $(window).scroll(function () { 
      $("span").css("display", "inline").fadeOut("slow"); 
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

See here the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4M7XK/ (minimize the height of the bottom right block)

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but I do not now the original article you are referring to, but here is idea, how I would make it work.

Once the users starts scrolling. (e.g. $(window).scroll(function(){...}) from jQuery ), I would place a empty div to  cover the whole page from top to bottom. This element would be above all other possibly scrollable divs, preventing them every catching the scroll event. It element has to be removed with a few miliseconds timeout.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var $cover = $('<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: '+ $(document).height() + 'px; z-index: 100000">asdasd</div>')
$cover.appendTo($("body"));
setTimeout(function(){
     $cover.remove();
},200); 
});
```